# Let H be a subgraph of G. Is it necessary true that $\chi'(H) \leq \chi'(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let H be a subgraph of G. Is it necessary true that $\chi'(H) \leq \chi'(G)$?

By definition of subgraph:

- Number of vertexes of H is equal or less then number of vertexes of G.
- Number of edges of H is equal or less then number of edges of G.

So $\chi'(H) \leq \chi'(G)$

Can I proof it in a better way? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: By $\chi'$ do you mean the Euler characteristic?

Comment: χ′ is the minimal number of different colors that's necessary to color the edges of the graph

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how what you've written constitutes a proof.

A proof would go: 
An edge $n$-coloring on $G$ is a function $f:E(G)\to [1,n]$ satisfying $f(\{v,w\})\ne f(\{v,w'\})$ when $w\ne w'$ (colorings are assumed to be surjective usually, but it doesn't matter for the definition of $\chi'$, and its simpler to omit that requirement). $\chi'(G)$ is defined to be the least $n$ such that an $n$-coloring exists. Note that if $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, $E(H)\subseteq E(G)$, so an edge $n$-coloring of $G$ can be restricted to $E(H)$ to give an edge $n$-coloring of $H$. Thus $\chi'(H)\le \chi'(G)$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the proof, in specific E(G)→[1,n] and f(v,w)≠f(v,w′). Can it be proven more easy?

Comment: That's the definition of an $n$-coloring, an assignment of at most $n$ colors to every edge of the graph, such that if two edges share a common vertex, then they have different colors. I edited it to $f(\{v,w\})$ to be more clear about that.

Comment: Sorry, I did not learn the E(G) notation. What does it mean?

Comment: Edges of the graph

Comment: So you say: When we edge color G and district G to H, we have an edge coloring for H with the same number of colors. I understand that the edge coloring of H can not be a coloring with more colors that G, but How do we know for sure that this edge coloring number is always 1) equal or 2) less than the edge coloring of G?

Comment: Because the edge coloring number of $H$ is the least colors necessary, and if we take a coloring of $G$ with $\chi'(G)$ colors, and restrict that to $H$, we get a coloring of $H$ with at most $\chi'(G)$ colors. Tho I'm not entirely sure I understood your question.

Comment: We optimaal edge color G and next district G to H, and Lets say that H has less points than G. Than 1) its possible that the edge coloring of H is still optimal, but 2) its also possible that H can be optimal colored with less colors. Is it possible to give an example for that cases?

Comment: Yes there are examples of both, but all we need is that it's less than or equal to, so it's ok. I'll give you examples: for the second, consider K4, It has edge coloring number 3, and it's subgraph K3 has edge coloring number 3, but it's subgraph K2 has edge coloring number 1.

Comment: Thnx. So by proving that the optimal coloring number of H is never higher than the optimal coloring number of G we have proved it?

Comment: Yes, that's a valid restatement of the proposition.

Comment: Which proposition is it? Is there a generaal notation of it?

Comment: What is the name of this method of proof?

Comment: I meant the proposition you're trying to prove. There is no name for this method of proof. (At least not that I know of) It's just a proof.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes:

1) Proving a universal statement like this "with an example" is almost never an acceptable proof. You need a general argument.

2) You haven't really given a proof here, since you jump straight from definitions to the answer that may not hold up to further questioning.

3) Typically, whenever you need to show something like $\chi'(H) \leq a$ for some $a$, you show that $a$ colors are enough to properly color the edges. This is because if $a$ colors are sufficient, then the minimum number of colors should be at most $a$. So for this problem, to show $\chi'(H) \leq \chi'(G)$, just show that you can properly edge-color $H$ with $\chi'(G)$ colors.

Comment: Ok, but by definition. H can be the same Graph as G so H can be edge colored with chi ‘ (G) colors. So the proof is complete?

Comment: $H$ CAN be the same graph as $G$, but it doesn't have to be. You are falling into the same trap as I wrote in (1). Instead, think more generally: we can edge-color $G$ with $\chi'(G)$ colors, so suppose we have such a coloring. Can we use this coloring to color $H$? Remember to justify your argument and not make any additional assumptions about $G$ or $H$.